# Modify report to come up with an average # of days when count = 6, average # of days when count = 7, average # of days when count = 8 etc

Tags: reporting-services, average

[image]I created a report that has a count of the # of cases assigned per day.  Originally, I grouped Date and Pathologist so I could get the count. then I hid the pathologist becuase I don't want the data by pathologist just by date.

Each column contains a count based on a specific # of day's for example case count of  6 per day, case count 7 per day, case count 8 per day. See the attached print screen.

I need to modify this report to get the average Days between a date range when a dr has  a case count = 6, case count = 7, case count = 8, etc.  I don't need this by dr just by date range for each different row (cases6, cases7, cases8, etc) .  I can calculate the average based on each day, but I don't know how to calculate the average based on a date range.

How would I modify this report to be able to come up with that information.

```
DECLARE 
@StartDate datetime = '07/01/2021', 
@EndDate datetime = '06/31/2022'

select 
cast(created_date as date) as Created_Date, 
p.full_name as Pathologist, 
CASE WHEN count(*) = 6 THEN 1 END as Cases6,
CASE WHEN count(*) = 7 THEN 1 END   as Cases7,
CASE WHEN count(*) = 8 THEN 1 END   as Cases8,
CASE WHEN count(*) = 9 THEN 1 END   as Cases9,
CASE WHEN count(*) = 10 THEN 1 END  as Cases10

from accession_2 a
where a.created_date >= @StartDate and a.created_date < = 
@EndDate
group by cast(created_date as date), p.full_name
order by cast(created_date as date)
```

Comment: This is one of the few times where we actually do need to see some sample data. Are the counts already done in the SQL or are they calculated in SSRS. Does a data row look like a row in SSRS or does each case have it's own row?

Comment: Sorry, I never know what exactly people are going to want to see.  This is an SSRS report based on a calculated query.

Comment: I added the query and more info about the report.  Please let me know if you need more info.